# Office 365 API to manage mail accounts and mail aliases with PHP

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, office365

We have a PHP-Application based on the Zend Framework. We recently switched from our own mailserver to office 365.

When we had our own mailserver we created mail accounts and mail aliases for our users automatically. I know want to implement that feature with our office 365 subsrcibtion.

I looked at the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn736059%28v=office.15%29.aspx

But i couldn't find any description on how manage the accounts and aliases in office 365. Does anybody know where I can find that in the docs?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Does office 365 even have an api?

Comment: Yes it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: That's what I like about SO, you always learn something new :)